# Input field not loosing focus when I update a value in it and thus Form Data didn't gets updated on Save Button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onfocus

I have a case where my Input fields are not getting updated on Save Button click, as it seems like they are not losing Focus when I update them and then immediately click on Save Button without clicking anywhere else on the Page.

Does anyone has identified this behavior? Please let me know if you have any articles/documentation for such scenarios.

Comment: I faced an issue when input field immediately lose focus as soon as I pressed a key. But I think you should show your code or provide jsFiddle or codepen link here.

Comment: Can you share the code were you try to do update/save your input fields?

Comment: @AndreNuechter, the Update part is just making a Post request with the form data. So the problem seems more related to React part.

Comment: @bravemaster, I think the case you are mentioning is what I need to, as my Input fields need to get Focussed Out when I click on Save button and also It should save the value filled within it.

Comment: Maybe you are listening for the wrong event, but it's hard to tell without any code, so good luck I guess.